# Configure ImageMagick on typo3

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I downloaded typo3 `typo3_src-7.6.6` on windows 8 und wrapped its content in the following path `C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3Test`. Afterwards I installed the ImageMagick in the following path `C:\xampp` but when I click the following `Install-->Test setup`   I am getting the error in the image below.

How can I fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install `Ghostscript` as instructed?

Comment: @MarkSetchell:  yes I installed it.

Comment: Please test your image generation by hand first. ``$ 'path to image magic' 'convert' +profile '*' -geometry 170x136!   'typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Public/Images/TestInput/Test.gif[0]' 'typo3temp/pics/installTool-write-gif.gif'``

Comment: Do not use your custom configuration. Select the radio button "Image Magick version 6 or higher" of the "Configuration Presets" tab of the Install Tool.

Answer (score -1):

[Screenshot of Systemproperties -> Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXHil.png)

I think you should add the path to ImageMagick in the systems environment variable "Path", like you see in the pic (German version)